# Reversing a string and palindrom time complexity in Python

Tags: python, string, list, palindrome

Is the code below code good for checking whether a string is palindrome or not?
What is its time complexity? I guess it's, `O(1)` am I right? Because we are just accessing the same string with different indexes and so accessing index `O(1)` is an operation. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Please provide a better solution, if possible.

```
s1 = 'abccba'
s2 = s1[::-1]
if s1==s2:
    print('Palindrome')
else:
    print('Not Palindrome')
```

Comment: Worst case complexity of slicing is O(n). Apart from that, worst case complexity of comparing two strings is O(n). So, the complexity of this solution is O(n).

Comment: Agree! but is it a good method to use ? or any better method can be there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def check_palin(word):
    for i in range(len(word)//2):
        if word[i] != word[-(i+1)]:
            return False
    return True
```

I guess this is a bit more efficient solution as it iterates over half of the string and returns `False` whenever the condition is violated. But still the complexity would be `O(n)`

Comment: to make sure the for loop range is in integer, we need to do an integer division by using `//`
`for i in range(len(word)//2):`

Comment: Sure @Sankar, For Python2.x we can use `/`, for Python 3.x we should use `//`. But for the sake of consistency, I will edit the answer to use `//`. Thanks for pointing out.